# Can we do s3:prefix to the resource having s3 bucket folder instead of bucket name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can we use S3:prefix on bucket folder instead of bucket name itself?

```
resources = "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/abc"
condition {
    test     = "StringLike"
    variable = "s3:prefix"
    values   = "json/*/"
}
```

Getting to know the response is it the valid way to put the syntax?

Comment: Note: S3 object keys don't start with `/`.

Comment: now corrected. will that works like giving folder name in resources instead bucket name and can we add "s3:prefix" condition

Comment: Your question is very vague and likely will not yield any good answers. Please try to improve the question by explaining what you are trying to do, what problem you are running into, and what the policy fragment you have included represents (is it part of a Terraform template for an S3 bucket policy or something else?)

Comment: Jarmod, I am facing issue like this I have posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77222683/invalid-value-for-args-parameter-argument-3-has-length-1-which-is-inconsiste