# Invalid value for "args" parameter: argument 3 has length 1, which is inconsistent with argument 2 of length 3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

```
locals {
  environment_map = {
    prd    = ["prd"]
    nonprd = ["dev", "qa", "stg"]
  }
  bucket_name = "test-bucket"
  account     =  "Prod" 

  consumers_config =  {
        client1 = {
          provider_url      = "www.google.com/abc/"
          source_id =         ["1001"]
        }
      }
  
  client_map = merge([
    for consumer, consumer_details in local.consumers_config : {
      for env, env_details in local.environment_map :
      "${consumer}_${env}" => {
        env               = env_details
        source_id_list = consumer_details["source_id"]
        provider_url      = consumer_details["provider_url"]
        audience_id       = "URN://${consumer}_${local.account_type}_AWS_${local.account}"
  } }]...)
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "read_policy" {

  for_each = var.client_specific_iam_roles ? local.client_map : {}
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:GetObjectAttributes",
      "s3:GetObjectVersion",
      "s3:GetObjectVersionAttributes"
    ]
    resources = concat(formatlist("arn:aws:s3:::%s/%s/test/test_json/*/source_id=%s/*",
      local.bucket_name,lookup(each.value, "env"), lookup(each.value, "source_id")))
  }
}
```

How can I iterate over map elements having different lengths as in here as env field and source_id_list are having different lengths but need to get iterated. replacing source_id_list value with one string element is solving the issue but if I need list of ids', how can I achieve the solution.

Comment: Please add where exactly does the error happen.

Comment: Thanks Mark, over here in resources = concat(formatlist("arn:aws:s3:::%s/%s/test/test_json/*/source_id=%s/*",
      local.bucket_name,lookup(each.value, "env"), lookup(each.value, "source_id")))
like as here env is having like ["dev", "qa", "stg"] and sourceid is having only one  ["1001"] field, it is throwing the error

Answer (score 0):

I think, in your case, the `setproduct` function ([docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/setproduct)) may come to your rescue.

The `setproduct` function allows you to obtain from two lists, e.g. `list_a = ["a", "b"]` and `list_b = ["1", "2", "3"]` all the possible combinations of the elements of list_a and list_b, by computing the Cartesian product (
`[ ["a", "1"], ["a", "2"], ["a", "3"], ["b", "1"], ["b", "2"], ["b", "3"] ]`).

In your specific case, you may create a new local:

```
    product_env_source_id = { for k, v in local.client_map : k => flatten([
      for entry in setproduct(v["env"], v["source_id_list"]) : concat(
        formatlist("ggarn:aws:s3:::%s/%s/test/test_json/*/source_id=%s/*",
          local.bucket_name,
          entry[0],
          entry[1]
      )) ]) }
```

This local would be a map with the same keys of `clients_map`, mapping to a list having a value for each element of the Cartesian product of a client's `env` and `source_id_list` lists.

You can then assign to your data `resources` field `local.product_env_source_id[each.key]`, obtaining something like this:

```
    data "aws_iam_policy_document" "read_policy" {
      for_each = var.client_specific_iam_roles ? local.client_map : {}
      statement {
        effect = "Allow"
        actions = [
          "s3:GetObject",
          "s3:GetObjectAttributes",
          "s3:GetObjectVersion",
          "s3:GetObjectVersionAttributes"
        ]
        resources = local.product_env_source_id[each.key]
      }
    }
```

To be clear of the value hold by `local.product_env_source_id`:

- with the following `client_config`

  ```
  consumers_config = {
      client1 = {
        provider_url = "www.google.com/abc/"
        source_id    = ["1001"]
      }
      client2 = {
        provider_url = "www.othersite.com/abc/"
        source_id    = ["1002", "1003"]
      }
    }
  ```
- then, `product_env_source_id` would be

  ```
  {
    "client1_nonprd" = [
      "ggarn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/dev/test/test_json/*/source_id=1001/*",
      "ggarn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/qa/test/test_json/*/source_id=1001/*",
      "ggarn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/stg/test/test_json/*/source_id=1001/*",
    ]
    "client1_prd" = [
      "ggarn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/prd/test/test_json/*/source_id=1001/*",
    ]
    "client2_nonprd" = [
      "ggarn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/dev/test/test_json/*/source_id=1002/*",
      "ggarn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/dev/test/test_json/*/source_id=1003/*",
      "ggarn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/qa/test/test_json/*/source_id=1002/*",
      "ggarn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/qa/test/test_json/*/source_id=1003/*",
      "ggarn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/stg/test/test_json/*/source_id=1002/*",
      "ggarn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/stg/test/test_json/*/source_id=1003/*",
    ]
    "client2_prd" = [
      "ggarn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/prd/test/test_json/*/source_id=1002/*",
      "ggarn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/prd/test/test_json/*/source_id=1003/*",
    ]
  }
  ```

Comment: Great Lorenzo, Thank you so much for this suggestion and clear explaination. will help me a lot.